# ReactJS, ES6: Using Arrow( => ) to modify state arrays' individual elements' member, a better way?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have itemList as my state array of objects.

```
    this.state = {
        .....
      itemList: [],
       .....
    }
```

itemList has `title, desc, expState`. The code present below works perfect. I want to know is there a better way to do it, like using arrow of ES6. I am new to ReactJS as well as ES6, so can't figure out.

```
    var index = this.state.itemList.indexOf(item);
    item.expState = !(item.expState);
    var newItemList = itemList;
    newItemList[index] = item;
    this.setState({itemList: newItemList});
```

Comment: `var newItemList = itemList; newItemList[index] = item;` -- this makes very little sense.

Comment: What are `itemList` and `item`? And what does this have to do with arrow functions? Also, if this code "works" then it's not suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: I am editing to add item and itemList details. I am asking if there is an ES6 version. 
@zerkms : can't there be a possibility when I don't want to modify my itemList? ;)

Comment: ES6's new arrow syntax has absolutely nothing to do with what you're attempting to do. I think what you really need are [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

Comment: @BhavyaArora you are modifying* `itemList` (*: to be entirely correct, you're modifying objects its elements refer to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item.expState = !item.expState;
this.setState({ itemList: this.state.itemList });
```

The code above is the simplified version of what you have (it's pretty much ES5.1 still, since there is no place to use anything from the new standards).

The part

```
var newItemList = itemList;
newItemList[index] = item;
```

was entirely removed since in JS arrays are not cloned on assignment, but only references to them are assigned to a variable. Hence you are working with the same array anyway.